# How can I do upsert (update and insert) query in MySQL Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I'm looking for a simple upsert (Update/Insert).

I have table in which I am inserting rows for books table but next time when I want to insert row I don't want to insert again data for that table just want to update with required columns if it exits there if not then create new row.

How can I do this in Mysql-python?

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO books (book_code,book_name,created_at,updated_at) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (book_code,book_name,curr_time,curr_time,))
```

Answer (score 11):

MySQL has [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)  statement:

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE`
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

```
cursor.execute("""
    REPLACE INTO books (book_code,book_name,created_at,updated_at)
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
    (book_code,book_name,curr_time,curr_time,)
)
```

**UPDATE** According to comment of @Yo-han, `REPLACE` is like `DELETE` and `INSERT`, not `UPSERT`. Here's alternative using [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO books (book_code,book_name,created_at,updated_at)
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE book_name=%s, created_at=%s, updated_at=%s
""", (book_code, book_name, curr_time, curr_time, book_name, curr_time, curr_time))
```

Comment: This is not a upsert. This is a DELETE and INSERT. To do a upsert you should use the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205207/808097) syntax.

Comment: @Yo-han, Thank you for the information. I updated to answer according to your comment.